# Ubuntu server not accessible (DigitalOcean)

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have a DigitalOcean droplot hosting an Ubuntu server which is refusing connections to all associated domains. I use ServerPilot to host WordPress websites, which is now showing a 'connection lost' error to my servers IP.

I'm unable to access my server via SFTP (FATAL ERROR: Connection refused) or SSH through my terminal (ssh: connect to host 159.65.89.6 port 22: Connection refused).

I can however access SSH through DigitalOcean web console.

When loggin in via web console, i receive the following error - And i believe my server goes into read only mode which is why it isn't accessible(?).

I have tried fsck to no avail.

[image: Server Error]

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to SSH from a terminal on an actual operating system (local BASH/ZSH) etc.? I don't know without more information, and port management on cloud services is notoriously a pain, but on DigitalOcean specifically - which I've had otherwise nothing but positive experiences with - you have to get your personal SSH key completely right.

In order to SSH to a DigitalOcean droplet, unless you have disabled security features, you *must* not only use the private counterpart to the public key you provided at droplet creation, but you have to make sure your login is identical. This is a problem if, for instance, you generated your keys without specifying a user (usually root to start out with, and then making a new one for accessing your user after you create one.

To give a concrete example: if you have OS X and use SSH-keygen, and your user account is jesse@yourcomputer, you won't be able to use that key to access the root user of your droplet at digital.ocean.ip. That's because the key authenticates you as jesse, not root. The solution here is to make a user called Jesse in DO's console and then access it. If you want to directly access root from your local terminal, you will need to generate an SSH keypair which has you as root, not your local username. It's a pain, but worth it given the value DigitalOcean provides.

This may not be the issue you're having - it sounds like several problems interacting - but this is the best advice I can give with the information you've given me.